# How to create table inside an Input type text (text field)?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to create a dynamic size table inside a text field(input type="text")
It is to be created by the click of a button, the table will be filled from within that text-box before the whole post being submitted.

So its a text box for blog posting, so that the table will be posted along with the text.

how to do that? (in the simplest way please).

Edit:
i was thinking is there a way to say highlight a certain part of the text and apply table html tags from there `<table><th><td>`? but what about the tag attributes?

Comment: Provide code you tried

Comment: You should show us an example of the inputs/outputs you want. I don't understand all your needs.

Comment: @TakitIsy the input is an input-button to create a table where the cursor is, inside the input-text box.
i don't have an example, i am at the start of my project, it is just some basic html tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't create a table inside a `input`.

⋅
⋅
⋅

But you can use a `div` with the `contenteditable` property to create a modifiable table:

```css
table td{
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 4px 12px;
}
```

```html
<div contenteditable=true>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>8</td>
      <td>9</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Hope it helps.